# Checking for int values within a string

Tags: python

Overall I'm trying to separate a list of usernames by credit hours. So I've taken them from a .txt file and added them to my initial list but now I'm trying to figure out how to check the credit hours in each line.

```
stud001 14
stud002 56
stud003 72
```

So far I've been trying to convert the credit hours into ints and then compare it directly from there but that won't work for me. I feel like I'm overthinking it but I'm not exactly sure where to go from here.

edit: So far what I've been trying is along the lines of this (I've tried a couple variations):

```
for x in lis:
    lis = eval(x[-2:])
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Just get the value... `int(line.split()[1])`

Answer (score 3):

**You could try doing it with a `lists of lists` like this:**

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:     #Replace 'file.txt' with your textfile
    lis=[]                           
    for line in f:
        lis.append(line.split())
```

This will create a list of lists, with the form:

```
[['stud001', '14'], ['stud002', '56'], ['stud003', '72']]
```

You can now iterate over and compare the credit hours.

**For example** (to access the first credit hour and its associated student number):

```
>>> lis[0][1]
14 
>>> lis[0][0]
stud001
```

**Also, if the data was given out of order:**

```
stud001 72      #switched 72 and 14
stud002 56
stud003 14
```

You could add the following line of code to sort the `list of lists` based on credit hours:

```
lis.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This would sort the list, `lis`, by lowest to highest credit hours:

```
>>> lis
[['stud003', '14'], ['stud002', '56'], ['stud001', '72']]
```

Comment: I don't think a `list` is an optimal data structure for data like these.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Agreed, a `dictionary` is a more convenient data structure. This is just a "lower number of lines" solution.

Comment: Fewer lines than one to open the file, one to create the dictionary, and one to print it?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 By "lower number of lines" I just meant one `for-loop` less lol. In the long run, a dictionary is the optimal solution because indexing with keys is more efficient.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 My bad! :( I thought the `for-loop` for printing the dictionary was included in making the dictionary .. I overlooked that, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

my_file.txt:

```
stud001 14
stud002 56
stud003 72
```

Code:

```
>>> with open('test5.txt', 'r') as f:
...     data = {}
...     for line in f:
...             line = line.strip().split()
...             data[line[0]] = int(line[1])
...
>>> for key in sorted(data):
...     print(key, data.get(key))
...
stud001 14
stud002 56
stud003 72
```

This can be expressed more tersely as such:

```
>>> with open('test5.txt', 'r') as f:
...     data = {line.strip().split()[0]:int(line.strip().split()[1]) for line in f}
...
>>> print(*(' '.join((k, str(data.get(k)))) for k in sorted(data)), sep='\n')
stud001 14
stud002 56
stud003 72
```

This creates a dictionary, `data`, containing keys like `"stud001"` and values like `14`. Then it prints each entry on a separate line, sorted by key in alphabetical order, with the key and value separated by a space.